# scipy.linalg.block_diag vs scipy.sparse.block_diag in terms of efficiency

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, coding-efficiency

I have a question about the way scipy builds block diagonal matrices. I was expecting that creating a sparse block diagonal matrix would be much quicker and more efficient than creating a dense one (because of sparsity compressions). But it turns out that it's not the case (or maybe am I using some inefficient method) :

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import block_diag as bd_sp
from scipy.linalg import block_diag as bd_la

m = [np.identity(1)] * 10000

before = timer()
res = bd_sp(m)
timer()-before
#takes 33.79 secs

before = timer()
res = bd_la(*m)
timer()-before
#takes 0.069 secs
```

What am I missing? Thank's in advance for your replies.

Comment: There surely is some additional overhead in sparse data-structures. I'm afraid, your artificial example somewhat diverges from a real-world scenario (it's just a diagonal-matrix and there is a dedicated function to do that; if it would consist of real blocks, dense-arrays will start to scale less good as far as dimensions grow, especially in regards to memory).

Comment: Actually, this example is not so artificial : I have a python script that starts with 100k one-dimensional identity matrices, that are agregated gradually by contructing block diagonal matrices.

Also, using R, the same algorithm runs much faster while using sparse matrices...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [625]: [np.identity(1)*i for i in range(1,5)]
Out[625]: [array([[1.]]), array([[2.]]), array([[3.]]), array([[4.]])]
In [626]: sparse.block_diag(_)
Out[626]: 
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [627]: _.A
Out[627]: 
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 3., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 4.]])
```

`block_diag` uses `bmat` to join the elements.  `bmat` makes `coo` matrices from all elements, and combines their attributes with offsets, and makes a new `coo` matrix. The code is readable Python.

It may be more efficient to construct your own `data, row, col` arrays.  `block_diag` is a convenience, and fine for combining a few large matrices, but not efficient when combining many small ones.

The `linalg` function is also Python (and pretty short).  If creates an `out` array of the right shape, and inserts the blocks with sliced indexing.  That's an efficient dense array solution.  Most of the hard work is done in compiled `numpy` code.

Sparse matrices can be faster when doing matrix multiplication (and related linalg solvers).  For most other operations, including initialization, they are slower than equivalent dense code.  They are also valuable when the problem is too big.